# Problem with conversion of data type in Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, types

I have column in DataFrame with number of evidence of clients ("col1").

When I check by `df.info()` data type of my "col1" it is "object" nevertheless I have in this column values like: 45667345.0000 and 1343543.

When I try to convert type of this column by: `df["col1"] = df["col1"].astype("int64")` I have error like:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '41231123.0'
```

What can I do to change type of this column ?

Comment: Try `df["col1"] = df["col1"].astype(float).astype("int64")`

Comment: If it's a string, you may want to `pd.to_numeric` first

Comment: Tom McLean you solution does not work erro like this: ValueError: could not convert string to float: '      _'

Comment: ifly6 you solution doeas not work error like this: ValueError: Unable to parse string "    _" at position 34147

Comment: `df.replace('_','',regex=True).astype(float).astype("int64")`?

Comment: Anurag Debas you solution does not work error like this: ValueError: could not conver string to float: "     ."

Comment: If there are truly errors and **they don't matter**, just `pd.to_numeric(YOUR_COLUMN, errors='coerce')`. If they do matter, you need to find your errors and correct them until there aren't any more of them.